# How can I define a macro in LISP with N arguments?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to define a macro in LISP, such as this caller function in a different file

```
(set_name name My name is Timmy)

(set_name occupation I am a doctor )

(defmacro set_name (list)
   (print list)
)
```

Comment: Macros are supposed to return new code to be executed in place of the macro call, not execute something immediately.

Comment: Can you give me an example ? sorry I am new to LISP, I just don't how to pass those arguments into define macro.

Comment: Why do you think this should be a macro in the first place, not a function?

Comment: The name suggests that it's supposed to set the variable, not print something. What do you really want to do?

Comment: I would suggest you read chapter 7 and 8 to get an understanding of CL’s macros http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just like in ordinary functions, use `&rest` to collect all the remaining arguments into a list.

```
(defmacro set_name (name &rest list) 
  `(setq ,name ',list))
(set_name occupation I am a doctor)
(print occupation)
```

This will print `(I AM A DOCTOR)`

You need to quote `,list` in the expansion so it won't try to evaluate all the symbols as variables.